# With my code, I'm having trouble with adding a loop to the end for the code to start over

Tags: java, loops, for-loop, while-loop

With my code, I need to a loop which starts the code over again. They say to "Embed your program inside a loop with the last statement/exit condition as a string equal to no" but I still don't understand where to put it and which loop to use.

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class addiePorterMod8Banking {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        int depositSavings, depositChecking, withdrawalSavings, withdrawalChecking, transferSavingsToChecking;
        int b, c, d, e, f, g, lp;
        int savingsaccount = 3000;
        int checkingaccount = 650;
        Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("What do you wish to do today?\n1 for deposit to savings\n2 for deposit to checking\n3 for withdraw from savings\n4 for withdraw from checking\n5 for transfer funds from savings to checking");
        int a = kbReader.nextInt();
        if (a == 1) {
            System.out.println("1-you chose to make a deposit to savings. How much would you like to deposit?");
            int answer = kbReader.nextInt();
            lp = savingsaccount + answer;
            System.out.println("Your total in savings is $" + lp);
        }
        if (a == 2) {
            System.out.println("2-you chose to make a deposit to checking. How much would you like to deposit?");
            int answer = kbReader.nextInt();
            lp = checkingaccount + answer;
            System.out.println("Your total in checking is $" + lp);
        }
        if (a == 3) {
            System.out.println("3-you chose to withdraw from savings. How much would you like to withdraw?");
            int bunny = kbReader.nextInt();
            lp = savingsaccount - bunny;
            System.out.println("Your total in savings is $" + lp);
        }
        if (a == 4) {
            System.out.println("4-you chose to withdraw from checking. How much would you like to withdraw?");
            int bubble = kbReader.nextInt();
            lp = checkingaccount - bubble;
            System.out.println("Your total in checking is $" + lp);
        }
        if (a == 5) {
            System.out.println("5-Your current balance in savings is $3000. How much would you like to transfer?");
            int awesome = kbReader.nextInt();
            lp = savingsaccount - awesome;
            int al = checkingaccount + awesome;
            System.out.println("Your total in checking is $" + al + "." + "Your total in savings is $" + lp + ".");
        }
        System.out.println("Would you like another transaction? 1 for yes. 2 for No");
        int more = kbReader.nextInt();

    }
}
```

Comment: Yikes. Please format your code; it's very hard to read as is

Comment: `while(!string.equals("no")) { //do logic}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `while` loop like below and when user enters `2`, break it

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void addiePorterMod8Banking (String args[]) {
        while (true) {
            int depositSavings, depositChecking, withdrawalSavings, withdrawalChecking, transferSavingsToChecking;
            int b, c, d, e, f, g, lp;
            int savingsaccount = 3000;
            int checkingaccount = 650;
            Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println("What do you wish to do today?\n1 for deposit to savings\n2 for deposit to checking\n3 for withdraw from savings\n4 for withdraw from checking\n5 for transfer funds from savings to checking");
            int a = kbReader.nextInt();
            if (a == 1) {
                System.out.println("1-you chose to make a deposit to savings. How much would you like to deposit?");
                int answer = kbReader.nextInt();
                lp = savingsaccount + answer;
                System.out.println("Your total in savings is $" + lp);
            }
            if (a == 2) {
                System.out.println("2-you chose to make a deposit to checking. How much would you like to deposit?");
                int answer = kbReader.nextInt();
                lp = checkingaccount + answer;
                System.out.println("Your total in checking is $" + lp);
            }
            if (a == 3) {
                System.out.println("3-you chose to withdraw from savings. How much would you like to withdraw?");
                int bunny = kbReader.nextInt();
                lp = savingsaccount - bunny;
                System.out.println("Your total in savings is $" + lp);
            }
            if (a == 4) {
                System.out.println("4-you chose to withdraw from checking. How much would you like to withdraw?");
                int bubble = kbReader.nextInt();
                lp = checkingaccount - bubble;
                System.out.println("Your total in checking is $" + lp);
            }
            if (a == 5) {
                System.out.println("5-Your current balance in savings is $3000. How much would you like to transfer?");
                int awesome = kbReader.nextInt();
                lp = savingsaccount - awesome;
                int al = checkingaccount + awesome;
                System.out.println("Your total in checking is $" + al + "." + "Your total in savings is $" + lp + ".");
            }
            System.out.println("Would you like another transaction? 1 for yes. 2 for No");
            int more = kbReader.nextInt();

            if (more == 2) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think it would be better to have `int more` outside the while loop and change the while loop conditional to: `while(more!=2){}`. Generally, infinite loops like `while(true)`, `for(;;)`, etc, are best to be avoided.

Answer (score 0):

While the Answer given by [Sand](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10632291/sand) above is completely correct considering the amount of conditions you are using which are not direct Boolean values it would end up faster and more efficient to use a switch case as well as saving you a small amount of typing with modern computers this shouldn't be an issue but none the less

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class addiePorterMod8Banking {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        while (true) {
            int depositSavings, depositChecking, withdrawalSavings, withdrawalChecking, transferSavingsToChecking;
            int b, c, d, e, f, g, lp;
            int savingsaccount = 3000;
            int checkingaccount = 650;
            Scanner kbReader = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.println(
                    "What do you wish to do today?\n1 for deposit to savings\n2 for deposit to checking\n3 for withdraw from savings\n4 for withdraw from checking\n5 for transfer funds from savings to checking");
            int a = kbReader.nextInt();
            switch (a) {
            case (1):
                System.out.println("1-you chose to make a deposit to savings. How much would you like to deposit?");
                int answer = kbReader.nextInt();
                lp = savingsaccount + answer;
                System.out.println("Your total in savings is $" + lp);
                break;
            case (2):
                System.out.println("2-you chose to make a deposit to checking. How much would you like to deposit?");
                int answer1 = kbReader.nextInt();
                lp = checkingaccount + answer1;
                System.out.println("Your total in checking is $" + lp);
                break;
            case (3):
                System.out.println("3-you chose to withdraw from savings. How much would you like to withdraw?");
                int bunny = kbReader.nextInt();
                lp = savingsaccount - bunny;
                System.out.println("Your total in savings is $" + lp);
                break;
            case (4):
                System.out.println("4-you chose to withdraw from checking. How much would you like to withdraw?");
                int bubble = kbReader.nextInt();
                lp = checkingaccount - bubble;
                System.out.println("Your total in checking is $" + lp);
                break;
            case (5):
                System.out.println("5-Your current balance in savings is $3000. How much would you like to transfer?");
                int awesome = kbReader.nextInt();
                lp = savingsaccount - awesome;
                int al = checkingaccount + awesome;
                System.out.println("Your total in checking is $" + al + "." + "Your total in savings is $" + lp + ".");
                break;
            }
            System.out.println("Would you like another transaction? 1 for yes. 2 for No");
            int more = kbReader.nextInt();

            if (more == 2) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

a little side note in case you arrant familiar with switch cases the brief is that they are similar to long chain conditionals but as soon as one task is done it doesn't continue to search for it through all values as a series of if statements does meaning as soon as something works it finishes instead of checking every condition and for cases in which aren't Boolean is considered faster read more [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/switch-vs-else/)